# Map zoom and selection JQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, mapping

I have an image that is pretty big. About 1000 x 1000 pixels. I need to display this in a 600 x 600 window. And I want users to be able to select "properties" on the map. These guys do a pretty good job using flash: http://www.simspro.co.za/omeya/map/

However, this is a bit overkill. I simply want an image where users can select spots off a map, and perhaps zoom in or scroll etc. What would best accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can use the JS mapping APIs available, i recommend [OpenLayers](http://www.openlayers.org).
With OpenLayers, you can create an "Image" layer, providing spatial registration/referencing (which can be as simple as the pixel coordinates), and then create point features with links and popups properties (cf. the OpenLayers examples : http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/image-layer.html).

ps : More infos on the [GIS StackExchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com).